# plpgsql didnt work in my greenplum 4.3.5.x

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, greenplum

code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dp_insert_trigger()
RETURNS trigger AS $dp_insert_trigger$
DECLARE
    tablename_1 text;
    tablename_2 text;
BEGIN
    RAISE WARNING 'Insert into process.';
    tablename_1='raw_kafka_input_dt2_1_prt_' || NEW.customer;
    tablename_2='raw_kafka_input_dt2_1_prt_' || NEW.customer || '_2_prt_' || NEW.method;

    IF not exists(select * from pg_class where  relname = tablename_1) THEN
        EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || tablename_1 || '(CHECK (customer=' || NEW.customer || ')) INHERITS (raw_kafka_input_dt2)';
        END IF;
    IF not exists(select * from pg_class where  relname = tablename_2) THEN
        EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || tablename_2 || '(CHECK (customer=' || NEW.customer || ' and method=' || NEW.method || ')) INHERITS (raw_kafka_input_dt2_1_prt_' || NEW.customer || ')';        
        END IF;
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || tablename_2 || ' VALUES (($1).*)';
    RETURN NULL; 
END;
$dp_insert_trigger$ language plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER dp_insert_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT ON raw_kafka_input_dt2
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE dp_insert_trigger();
```

i try to print some info like:

```
RAISE WARNING 'Insert into process.';
```

but nothing output but:

```
eqbase=# insert into raw_kafka_input_dt2 select * from raw_kafka_input_dt0 limit 1;
INSERT 0 1
eqbase=#
```

So,i am confused did trigger fired when i insert ?
my pg is 8.2 any suggestion is grateful.

Comment: Are you trying to create partitions on the fly? You should look into ALTER TABLE ... ADD PARTITION and check the default partition syntax as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things wrong here with the first being Greenplum doesn't support triggers.  Greenplum is an analytics and data warehousing database so you shouldn't be trying to use OLTP features.

Comment: thanks,the officer say it is "Full ACID compliant transactional database."
when i use pivotal optimizer,it output gp dont support this feature.but when i use legacy optimizer,nothing like above are output but still didnt fired the trigger.does this mean sth?

Comment: ACID compliant doesn't mean it supports triggers.  It just means that I can commit and rollback data using transactions with isolation and durability.